# Download files from a list using wget

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a file which contains downloading links like this:

```
Google.com/image2
Google.com/image3
Google.com/image4
Google.com/image5
Google.com/image6
```

I want to download all of them using a script. If the name starts with 's' download this file to the `s` directory, if it's b, then move it to `b` directory...

Answer (score 11):

Download all files, then move them using shell globs:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wget -i /path/to/download_list
mv s* ./s/
mv b* ./b/
```

- `-i`: Read URLs from a local or external file.

You might get a warning:

```bsh
mv: cannot move 's' to a subdirectory of itself.
```

That's fine, you can ignore it, or use `find` instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wget -i /path/to/download_list
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "s*" -type f -exec mv "{}" ./s \;
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "b*" -type f -exec mv "{}" ./b \;
```

---

And with a `for` loop you can run in on all alphabets, script name is `script.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wget -i /path/to/download_list
mkdir -p {a..z}
for l in {a..z};
do
    find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "${l}*" -not -iname script.sh -exec mv "{}" "./${l}" \;
done
```

Comment: i want with scripts

Comment: What you are seeing in my answer is a simple script, save it in a file, make it executable, then run it. You have to change it so it suits your needs.

Comment: if file name starting c or x or k ? write all variants?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question, then you have to use a loop, I'll update the answer.

Comment: uea ,i want to use loop

Comment: `mv s?* s/; mv b?* b/` will also work to prevent the inclusion of the move targets in the glob expressions. For the `find` variant you can make use of the `-exec ... +` action if you use the `-t` flag of `mv`: `find ... -exec mv -t TARGET -- {} +`.

Answer (score 5):

An addition to @Ravexina's nice answer.

Solution without a loop:

```bsh
wget -i /path/to/download_list
mkdir -p {a..z}
# mv the files with rename tool
rename 's/^((.).+)$/$2\/$1/' *
# clean up empty directories
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[a-z]' -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to download directly into the desired folder:

```bsh
# expand file to list and iterate
for path in $(<"/path/to/download_list"); do
    # get file part of path
    name=$(basename "$path")
    # use first character of name as dir
    dir=${name:0:1}
    # create dir is not exist
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    # download path directly to dir
    wget "$path" -P "$dir"
done
```